# Jira API - Set Assignee and Apply Transition in 1 Call

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

Is it possible to set an assignee and apply a transition (change status) in a single call to the Jira Cloud REST API? The example from the documentation [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v2/api-group-issues/#api-rest-api-2-issue-issueidorkey-transitions-post) seems to imply that you can, but it does not work when I tested it.

Here's some examples (with `curl`):

##### setting an assignee works

```
curl --request PUT \
    --url "https://mysite.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/project-123" \
    --user "johnsmith@example.com:abcdef1234567890abcdef00" \
    --header "Accept: application/json" \
    --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
    --data '{
        "fields": {
            "assignee": { "accountId": "987654321fedcba987654321" }
        }
    }'
```

##### applying a transition works too

```
curl --request POST \
    --url "https://mysite.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/project-123/transitions" \
    --user "johnsmith@example.com:abcdef1234567890abcdef00" \
    --header "Accept: application/json" \
    --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
    --data '{
        "transition": { "id": 1 }
    }'
```

##### error saying that assignee cannot be set

```
curl --request POST \
    --url "https://mysite.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/project-123/transitions" \
    --user "johnsmith@example.com:abcdef1234567890abcdef00" \
    --header "Accept: application/json" \
    --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
    --data '{
        "fields": {
            "assignee": {
                "accountId": "987654321fedcba987654321"
            }
        },
        "transition": {
            "id": 1
        }
    }'
```

##### sets assignee, but doesn't apply transition

```
curl --request PUT \
    --url "https://mysite.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/project-123" \
    --user "johnsmith@example.com:abcdef1234567890abcdef00" \
    --header "Accept: application/json" \
    --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
    --data '{
        "fields": {
            "assignee": {
                "accountId": "987654321fedcba987654321"
            }
        },
        "transition": {
            "id": 1
        }
    }'
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do that in one request because you're sending them to two different URLs.

Comment: Again, the example in the documentation seems to imply that you can do it all in one call (to the `/transitions` URL). I know that the current examples I made that work go to 2 different URLs, but I want to know if it's possible to use just one URL (which might require different formatting on the data).

Answer (score 0):

On JIRA Server 8.7.1, was able to successfully transition using the `name` property (instead of `accountId`).

```
curl --request POST \
    --url "https://mysite.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/project-123/transitions" \
    --user "johnsmith@example.com:abcdef1234567890abcdef00" \
    --header "Accept: application/json" \
    --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
    --data '{
        "fields": {
            "assignee": {
                "name": "will"
            }
        },
        "transition": {
            "id": 1
        }
    }'
```

Otherwise I got the following error:

```
{
    "errorMessages": [],
    "errors": {
        "assignee": "expected Object containing a 'name' property"
    }
}
```